# Use natural sorting when querying MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have home some data in a table that looks like this.

```
+------+
| code |
+------+
| Z1   |
| Z2   |
| Z3   |
| Z4   |
| Z10  |
| Z11  |
| Z12  |
| Z13  |
| Z20  |
| ZA   |
| ZBN  |
| ZFJK |
| ZX   |
+------+
```

Running `SELECT code FROM codes` returns:

```
+------+
| code |
+------+
|   Z1 |
|  Z10 |
|  Z11 |
|  Z12 |
|  Z13 |
|   Z2 |
|  Z20 |
|   Z3 |
|   Z4 |
|   ZA |
|  ZBN |
| ZFJK |
|   ZX |
+------+
```

What I like to do is to get the 3 first codes `Z1`, `Z2` and `Z3` by something like `SELECT code FROM codes WHERE code >= 'Z1' LIMIT 3`. This statement however returns, which is expected considering how MySQL sorts data the following data.

```
+------+
| code |
+------+
|   Z1 |
|  Z10 |
|  Z11 |
+------+
```

After getting the 3 first codes I like to get the 3 codes following the 3 first codes. Something like this `SELECT code FROM codes WHERE code > 'Z3' LIMIT 3` and then get `Z4`, `Z10` and `Z11`. And after that the next 3 items `Z12`, `Z13` and `Z20` and so on.

I'm able to get the output `naturally` sorted with a procedure if I query all the items but I only want to have 3 items, following the 3 previous returned based on `natural` sorting. Can I achieve this in MySQL or should I just get all the data and manipulate the data in program that is querying the database?

SQLFiddle -> [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc4db9)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an lpad  in order by

```
SELECT code FROM codes
order by lpad(code , 8,'0')
```

Comment: It sorts `Z1`, `Z2`, `Z3`, `Z4`, `ZA`, `ZX`, `Z10`, `Z11` and so on. Seem like it is mixing numbers and letters.

Comment: try explain better the order you need .. seems not  a natural order  ..

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you want (as i understand it) to sort the data first by the alphabetical part and then by the numeric part so that the order you get is:

```
+------+
| code |
+------+
| Z1   |
| Z2   |
| Z3   |
| Z4   |
| Z10  |
| Z11  |
| Z12  |
| Z13  |
| Z20  |
| ZA   |
| ZBN  |
| ZFJK |
| ZX   |
+------+
```

However, you can't do this directly in SQL as it will order the whole string as one unit of information.

So you need to split the string into two pieces but the length of the alphabetical part is variable and there is no delimiter between the two.

The first solution is to add a delimeter to the code (if you can) so that they are as follows:

```
+-------+
| code  |
+-------+
| Z-1   |
| Z-2   |
| Z-3   |
| Z-4   |
| Z-10  |
| Z-11  |
| Z-12  |
| Z-13  |
| Z-20  |
| ZA    |
| ZBN   |
| ZFJK  |
| ZX    |
+-------+
```

This will allow you to split the string into two strings by finding the location of the delimiter and sort them separately.

If you can't put in a delimiter (as this is already defined) then you will need to write a function in SQL to split the two strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that `Z` is one character long:

```
WHERE     0+MID(code, 2) > 1
ORDER BY  0+MID(code, 2)
```

If the alpha prefix is variable length, then the code become "too messy to do in SQL".  It would be slightly easier with MariaDB, which has things like `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.